# How to Calculate Hourly Average Pollution Across Multiple Stations in R for a Full Year

Tags: r, average

I have trouble calculating the average of 8 different stations. I have a dataset pollution contaminants hourly that contains hourly air pollution measurements for 8 different stations for the year 2022. The dataset has a date hourly column that contains the date and hour for each measurement there are 8 measurements in every hour. I want to find the average pollution across all stations for every hour of the day for the entire year. I have written the following code, but it doesn't seem to be working:
[This is the dataset I work with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFIKs.png)

```
hourly_average_pollution <- data.frame()
for (data_daily in "2022-01-01":"2022-12-31") {
    hourly_average <- pollution_contamimants_hourly %>%
        filter(Stations) %>%
        summarise(avg_pollution = mean(Pollution))
hourly_average_pollution <- rbind(hourly_average_pollution, cbind(hourly_average, data_daily))}
```

[This is the dataset I produce with that code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gxb3S.png)
Can someone help me fix this code so that I can calculate the hourly average pollution for all 8 stations for the whole year? It's like I want to make one Station of all. Thanks in advance!

To find a solution to the problem I have.

---

Please correct this code, and confirm if the result produced is correct (if your data is different, please correct the below code):

```
lines <- "CODI_CONTAMINANT ESTACIO ANY MES DIA_Hours Pollution date_daily 
193627 8 4 '2022-3-4' 19 31.00 '2022-03-04 19:00:00' 
45404 6 54 '2022-8-7' 24 0.20 '2022-08-08 00:00:00' 
65161 6 57 '2022-9-26' 4 0.40 '2022-09-26 04:00:00' 
308579 12 54 '2022-8-11' 22 16.00 '2022-08-11 22:00:00' 
497690 998 43 '2022-8-5' 6 4999.00 '2022-08-05 06:00:00'
402858 101 57 '2022-11-6' 3 1.98 '2022-11-06 03:00:00'"

DF <- read.table(text = lines, header = TRUE)
```

Produces:

[image]

Comment: can you please dput() the sample data?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. It has a lot of observations and when I do that it doesn't allow me to paste it because it's too long

Comment: These are unique values of the stations: [1] 57 54 43 44 42 50  4 58. And this for the dates: "2022-03-21 14:00:00 UTC"

Comment: You could please use sample() and some 40-50 observations (rows) so that we get an idea about it. Thanks.

Comment: CODI_CONTAMINANT ESTACIO  ANY MES DIA Hours Pollution          date_daily
193627                8       4 2022   3   4    19     31.00 2022-03-04 19:00:00
45404                 6      54 2022   8   7    24      0.20 2022-08-08 00:00:00
65161                 6      57 2022   9  26     4      0.40 2022-09-26 04:00:00
308579               12      54 2022   8  11    22     16.00 2022-08-11 22:00:00
497690              998      43 2022   8   5     6   4999.00 2022-08-05 06:00:00
402858              101      57 2022  11   6     3      1.98 2022-11-06 03:00:00

Comment: Desc_Contaminant
193627                           NO2
45404                             CO
65161                             CO
308579                           NOx
497690 Flow C (Mesura interna equip)

Comment: Thanks so much here is the sample that I created

Comment: I have edited your question, please first confirm if the data table is correctly produced from your sample data? otherwise, just modify the R code to produce correct table (and attached output picture).

Comment: Mes Contains only the month its from 1 to 12. DIA only the day from 1 to 30. ANY is the year. Data_daily is the column that contains all the dates combined. Codi_Contaminant is the code that represents the pollution. ESTACIO the number of the station.

Comment: Can I text you privately please

Comment: yes please, it will be better.